# Control over memory while working with linked lists in C

Tags: c, list, memory, memory-leaks, linked-list

While dealing with linked lists (LL), let us say we are writing a function insert(parameters) to insert a new node into d LL. For that we write in the function something similar to:

```
temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

That means we are allocating some space to 'temp'. After returning from the function this temp variable loses its scope and also its lifetime is over. So its dead now. But now my doubt is:

"Is the memory we have allocated now completely in our control even after returning from the function ?"

I am asking about OUR control on the newly allocated memory. We get results when we print or do any operations; but is that memory still dedicated to us? If the environment (OS) wants to use that memory is it restricted or it has permissions to use that memory?

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: It's not the memory that's out of scope, only the pointer.

Comment: @H2CO3 yeah i think the question i asked in a bit ambiguous way... can you please elaborate me about what happens if u understand my question.. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't call `free()`, the memory is still allocated for your use.  If `temp` goes out of scope, you leaked it though - how are you going to find out where it is to use it?

Answer (score 0):

The memory stays allocated until it is `free()`d, even if you lose track of it by letting all of the pointers to it go out of scope. Someone is always "in charge" of freeing allocated memory; the documentation for functions should tell you if they either take control of a pointer from you or give it to you (such as `malloc()` itself does by passing back a pointer). You are probably leaking memory here.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear :
The memory allocated is allocated by you program. Exiting your program will clean it. until then it is only for your personnal use.

the only limit is if you OS refuses to allocathe this memory. (see manual of malloc)

Also loosing track of this allocated memory does not clean it, it is just inaccessible (this is called a leak, you loosed your memory. But don't worry the OS will be able to retrieve it at exit)

Comment: This is not what the question is about.